# Probabiity rolls a standard

Tags: probability

Misha rolls a standard, fair six-sided die until she rolls 1-2-3 in that order on three consecutive rolls. The probability that she will roll the die an 4 time,5 time,6time ....denote $P_{4},P_{5}..$
Find $P_{4},P_{5}$. And prove that $\frac{P_{4}+P_{6}+....}{P_{5}+P_{7}+...}=\frac{P_{3}+P_{5}+...}{P_{4}+P_{6}+...}$
I find $P_{4}=\frac{6}{6^6-6} $but i don’t know right?
Because 1123,2123,3123,4123,5123,6123

Comment: The solution is given in the above link.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2018_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_13

Comment: Can you find $P_{4},P_{5}$ i don’t understand solution that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the second solution you get the relationship that

$$P_n = x\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-3} P_i\right)$$

$$P_4 = x\left(1-P_1\right) = x$$

$$P_5 = x\left(1-P_1-P_2\right)$$

where $x = \frac{1}{216}$ and $P_1=0$ and $P_2 = 0$

Thus $P_3 = P_4=P_5 = \frac{1}{216}$

_ _ _ 1 2 3 the 6 rolls of the die.  The first three could be anything other than 1 2 3 in that order. There are 216($6^3$) ways you fill the first three positions of which 1 2 3 ( just one) should not be the one.  Thus it is 216-1 = 215 Thus the probability is $\frac{215}{6^6}$.  That is the reasoning but you can find that using the recurrence relation.

Comment: Why $P_{6}=\frac{215}{6^6}$

Comment: I have given the reasoning but further $P_7, P_8,...$ could be understood using the building blocks with the reasoning that the last three is 1-2-3 and the previous rolls should not have 1-2-3.

Comment: This problem is difficult to understand if you can't reason P_3, P_4 and P_5 lowest orders.  Are you asked to solve it as part of the homework or is it beyond your comprehending ability( not because you are such but by training).

Comment: Thank you .i understand idea of problem