# Understanding solutions to a probability AIME question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, summation, contest-math

> Person $A$ rolls a standard, fair six-sided die until he rolls $1-2-3$ in that order on three consecutive rolls. I know the probability he stops rolling after an odd number of rolls is $\frac{216}{431}$. For each way I'm not really sure how to formalize it or I'm not sure how to justify certain claims.

For instance, one way is as follows: Let $P_n$ be the probability person $A$ rolls the die $n$ times. Clearly $P_n = 0$ for $n < 3$ and $P_3 = \frac{1}{6^3}$. I'm not sure how to show that $P_{2n + 1} = P_{2n} - \frac{P_{2n-2}}{6^3}.$ Clearly any sequence contributing to $P_{2n+1}$ must end in $1-2-3,$ and its first $2n-2$ terms cannot contain $1-2-3$ as consecutive terms, but I'm not sure how to use this to prove the recurrence. With this claim though, letting $x = P_3+P_5+\cdots = 1-(P_4 + \cdots)$, one easily sees that $x-\frac{1}{6^3} = (1-\frac{1}{6^3})(1-x)$ and solving gives the required probability.

> A similar technique is to define $S(n)$ to be the number of strings of digits from $1-6$ that do not contain the substring $123$ and note that $S(n)=6S(n-1)-S(n-3)$ since there are $6$ ways to append a character to $S(n-1)$ and the only possible occurrence of the substring $123$ in such a string can be at the end. All these occurrences of the substring $123$ at the end are counted by $S(n-3)$. Even more formally, one can easily define a bijection between  the subset of the set of strings counted by $S(n-1)$ consisting of strings ending in $12$ and the set of strings counted by $S(n-3)$.

Another way is to define the variables $a, b,c$ as follows. Call a sequence of rolls an even sequence if $1-2-3$ first occurs as the last three rolls of a sequence of an even number of rolls and an odd sequence if it occurs as the last three rolls of a sequence of an odd number of rolls. Let $a$ be the probability that person $A$ rolls an odd sequence, $b$ be the conditional probability that person $A$ rolls an odd sequence given his first roll is a $14,$ and let $c$ be the conditional probability that person $A$ rolls an odd sequence given that his first two rolls are $1-2$. Person $A$ can roll an odd sequence by rolling a $1$ on his first roll with probability $\frac{1}6$ and then getting an odd sequence with probability $b$ or by rolling something that's not a $1$ with probability $\frac{5}6$ followed by rolling an even sequence with probability $1-a$. So $a = \frac{1}6 b + \frac{5}6 (1-a)$. Though I'm not sure how to formalize why if person $A$ doesn't roll a one initially, then they can roll an even sequence with probability $1-a$. Intuitively, this makes sense because $a$ is the sum of infinitely many probabilities $P_3+P_5+\cdots$ defined in the first solution. Similarly, one can come up with the relations $b = \frac{1}6 (1-b) + \frac{1}6 c + \frac{4}6 a, c =\frac{1}6 b +\frac{1}6 + \frac{4}6 (1-a).$ The formal proofs for these relations are probably similar too.

> I was wondering how these two solutions can be formalized?

> **Edit:** I would like to point out that though this question is a duplicate of an AoPs problem, the second solution isn't from AoPs but from the Russian School. Also, I already have solutions; the key to this question is **understanding** the solutions I've presented.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2018_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_13

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probabiity rolls a standard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147702/probabiity-rolls-a-standard)

Comment: Also the question was asked $4$ days ago... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4383392/probability-you-end-dice-rolling-sequence-with-1-2-3-and-odd-total-number-of-rol

Comment: @MathLover thanks, but I think you're misunderstanding the point of my question. I want to understand solution 0 on AoPs better and to understand the russian school solution better too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is how the first solution can be obtained**

For the first occurrence to be on roll $2n+1$, there must have been no occurrence by roll $2n-2$ followed by $1-2-3$. Therefore, for $n\ge 1$,
$$P_{2n+1}=(1-P_0-P_1-...-P_{2n-2})\times (\frac {1}{6})^3.$$
Similarly, for $n\ge 2$,$$P_{2n}=(1-P_0-P_1-...-P_{2n-3})\times (\frac {1}{6})^3.$$
Subtracting, for $n\ge 2$, $$P_{2n+1}=P_{2n}-P_{2n-2}\times (\frac {1}{6})^3.$$
Summing over all $n$, $$x-(\frac {1}{6})^3=(1-x)\times (1-(\frac {1}{6})^3)\text { and  }x=\frac{216}{431}.$$